# Lazy loading not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error when try to navigate to 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard' lazy loading route  in angualr, angualr-cli 6.0.0

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module
>   "app/dashboard/dashboard.module". Error: Cannot find module
>   "app/dashboard/dashboard.module".
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:5

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule',

    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: MasterComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'login
    }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: it should be './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' no?

Comment: Thanks it works, 
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f44a2c730a84cd86695d1851395ad28423704bd0 (@samalexander committed 3 days ago)

Comment: Post that as an answer, will upvote ;)

Comment: good to know, good luck

Answer (score 12):

In previous versions loadChildren path support with 'app/path/to/module#Module' but  it's not working anymore, instead  of that use relative path './path/to/module#Module'

> angular/aio/content/examples/lazy-loading-ngmodules
>   example also has been changed 3 days ago with Angular 6 release
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f44a2c730a84cd86695d1851395ad28423704bd0
>
> **Angular community has been responding to the issue which I raised, Please find the responses below.**
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673#issuecomment-391786453
>
> *According to responses of angular community they will update document.*

usage need to change from

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: 'app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: 'app/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

> One other tip:
>
> Module import order matters
>   https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters

Comment: Another solution: https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters

* The order of  imports around. (Move the *RoutingModule to the bottom of the list of imports)
* Also removed the lazy-loaded modules from the NgModule.imports property list

Comment: The community has been opened in another issue regarding document changes 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673#issuecomment-391817263

Comment: That `One other tip` saved me! Thanks

Comment: Nice job pointing out the 'order matters'! Hours of swearing before I got to this.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same problem, but in angular 6 it seems that every module loaded with "lazy loaded" has to be removed from the `imports` declaration in the root module (`app.module.ts`). At least for me that works.

Comment: Exactly my issue. If you think about it why, should you import that lazy module into root? Defeats the purpose of lazy loading the chunk all-together.

Answer (score 4):

using angular 7

this works for me

```
loadChildren = 'src/app/layout/waay/lazy.module.ts#LazyModule';
```

and in

`angular.json`

```
...
"lazyModules": [
            "src/app/layout/waay/lazy.module.ts",
]
```

---

maybe this helps someone debugging the lazy load paths -->

(this might be subject to change in upcoming angular versions)

in chrome

- open the dev tools 
  <kbd>F12</kbd>
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (letter O)
- (a search prompt opens)
- on the keyboard, type "`lazyroute`"
- (it should list
  `$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object`)
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

now it should show you the contents of the map that angular/webpack uses to
look up the lazy routes

*$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object* (beginning of file)

```
var map = {
    "src/app/layout/waay/lazy.module.ts": [
        "./src/app/layout/waay/lazy.module.ts"
    ],
    "src/app/pages/even/more-lazy.module.ts": [
        "./src/app/pages/even/more-lazy.module.ts",
        "default~src-app-pages-even-more-lazy-module-ts~src-app-pages-some-page-module-ts~sr~2cb20cb3",
        "default~src-app-pages-even-more-lazy-module-ts~src-app-pages-counter-page-module~7852bff4",
        "common",
        "src-app-pages-even-more-lazy-module-ts"
    ],
    "src/app/pages/too/lazy-to-be-true.module.ts": [
        "./src/app/pages/too/lazy-to-be-true.module.ts",
        "default~src-app-pages-too-lazy-to-be-true-module-ts~src-app-pages-some-page-modu~c179459d",
        "default~src-app-pages-too-lazy-to-be-true-module-ts~src-app-pages-home-home-page-module-ts~src-app-~50ff7d88",
        "default~src-app-pages-too-lazy-to-be-true-module-ts~src-app-pages-home-home-page-module-ts",
        "common",
        "src-app-pages-too-lazy-to-be-true-module-ts"
    ],
    ...
};
```

the map gives you the relation between `module path` and `modules to be loaded` for the given module path.

by looking at this map it might help you to find out why some paths couldn't be resolved.

you can also put a breakpoint in the following line to step through it via debugger and get a clear understanding of where it might fail in the lookup.

*$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object*  (further down the file)

```
function webpackAsyncContext(req) {
    var ids = map[req];           // <-- put a breakpoint there, lookup in the map happens here
    if(!ids) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
            var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
            e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
            throw e;
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

hope this helps someone, it did the trick for me

Comment: This was a great explanation, Thanks a lot mate. Easier to debug now.

Comment: thank you Debadatta, really glad it helped you! :))

Comment: should it not be a : rather than a = ?

Answer (score 3):

For me modifying this

```
loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule',
```

To

```
loadChildren: () => AdminLayoutModule,
```

Worked and don't forget to import the module file.

Hope it help!

Comment: True, but that's eager loading.

Comment: Where are you deploying? I did deploy on Azure App service and its working for me.

Comment: It requires JIT to compile the resources because that's dynamic loading. It won't work with AOT enabled production builds, but you can work with it in your local.

Comment: This worked but you have to import the module too. thaks

Answer (score 2):

Efectively, there are **three posible workarounds**:

- Make use of relative path `loadChildren: './dashboard...`
- Absolute path but starting from /src: `loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard...`
- On `tsconfig.json`, set `BaseUrl: "./src"`

You can follow the progress of this [issue in Angular's repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673)

(*) Edited, thankfully this changed on latest versions with arrow functions lazy loading

Comment: Absolute path but starting from /src: loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard...
it should be start from 'app/exampleroute'
https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: Yeap, baseUrl has changed to root of angular project because of it would contain multiple applications.
They opened [an issue for updating documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) and making use of relative paths.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was changing the tsconfig.json to set the BaseUrl to "./src".

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked when I replaced `loadchildren` with `component`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when started use Angular Cli 9. For resolve, need to rewrite loadChildren next way

```
{path: 'admin', canLoad: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)},
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked like :-

```
{path: 'Customer', loadChildren: () => import('../Customer/CustomerModule').then(mod => mod.CustoModule)},
```

This is *separate file* for routing, I didnt made my routing in app.routing, so if you too have done like me, then please remove **"AppRoutingModule"** in imports, in module file. Then only it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

thankfully this changed on latest versions with arrow functions lazy loading

Comment: Please provide quality answers until you can write comments. This commentary like answer is not enough.